# How to install multiple blogs?

Tags: wordpress

I want to install multiple blogs using wordpress

Condition is through one wordpress installation and using one database. So how is it possible.

I have search and find that wordpress installation can use one database but for blog we should use different wordpress installtion.

Please help How to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "install" multiple blogs. You would have multiple categories. You can then use the menu editor to link menu items to the categories. If you mean multiple sites, then you would want to set up a WordPress multisite installation (see [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) on WordPress' Codex).